# In DB2, is it possible to have just a single trigger for both update and insert?

Tags: triggers, db2

I have to create the trigger(s) which will keep the audit of my table. The trigger is supposed to execute on both insert and update.

currently i am having two triggers

**One for Insert**:

```
CREATE TRIGGER SCH.TRG_TBL1_AFT_I
  AFTER INSERT ON SCH.TBL1  
  REFERENCING
    NEW AS n
  FOR EACH ROW
 MODE DB2SQL
INSERT INTO SCH.TBL1_AUDIT
VALUES( .. ,, .. );
```

**Another for update**

```
CREATE TRIGGER SCH.TRG_TBL1_AFT_U
  AFTER UPDATE ON SCH.TBL1  
  REFERENCING
    NEW AS n
  FOR EACH ROW
 MODE DB2SQL
INSERT INTO SCH.TBL1_AUDIT
VALUES( .. ,, .. );
```

But the point is, if it possible to create a single trigger, in DB2, for doing the task? [ provided both, trigger are doing the same thing .]

Comment: It's not possible in any other database either, right? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @RashmiPandit: You can at least do it in Oracle and Postgres

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry, DB2 doesn't offer a way to combine update and insert triggers together.

Answer (score 4):

Try this, the feature has been available since version 9.7.x.

```
CREATE or replace TRIGGER PASSENGER_TR01_BEFORE_IUD
 BEFORE 
    DELETE
 OR UPDATE OF FIRST_NAME 
 OR INSERT ON PASSENGER
REFERENCING 
OLD AS oldRow
NEW AS newRow
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (1=1) 
Begin
Declare ACTION Char(1) Default '';
-- Use Case/When to inquire trigger-event
Case 
When INSERTING Then
    Set ACTION='I';
When UPDATING  Then
    Set ACTION='U';    
When DELETING  Then
    Set ACTION='D';    
Else
    Set ACTION='N';    
End Case;

-- Use If/Then/Else to inquire trigger-event
If INSERTING Then
    Set ACTION='I';
ElseIf UPDATING  Then
    Set ACTION='U';
ElseIf DELETING  Then
    Set ACTION='D';
Else
    Set ACTION='N';    
End If;
End
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible.  **[See the documentation of create trigger](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_createtrigger.htm)**.  Here is a paste:

```
trigger-event

   .-OR--------------------------------------.   
   V                                     (4) |   
|----+-INSERT--------------------------+-----+------------------|
     +-DELETE--------------------------+         
     '-UPDATE--+---------------------+-'         
               |     .-,-----------. |           
               |     V             | |           
               '-OF----column-name-+-'
```

That would enable you to say:

`create trigger blah before insert on blah or update of blah`.

Answer (score 0):

[You can find more info here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibmi/library/i-event_triggers_support/)

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SET_SALARY
 NO CASCADE
 BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT ON employee
 REFERENCING NEW AS n OLD AS o
 FOR EACH ROW
 WHEN( o.edlevel IS NULL OR n.edlevel > o.edlevel )
 BEGIN
    -- Give 10% raise to existing employees with new education level.
 IF UPDATING THEN SET n.salary = n.salary * 1.1;
     -- Give starting salary based on education level.
 ELSEIF INSERTING THEN
     SET n.salary = CASE n.edlevel WHEN 18 THEN 50000
  WHEN 16 THEN 40000
         ELSE 25000
  END;
  END IF;
 END
```